# Is it possible to invert the colors of a webpage in the code when printing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a website that is entirely black and white (with a few color trims), however the black is overwhelmingly the largest portion of the page. I'd like the page to be more ink efficient by inverting all the colors when you go to print it. (making white the majority of the page)

Comment: Use a print style sheet. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [WebKit-based browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#WebKit-based), add to CSS:

```
@media print {
    html {
        -webkit-filter: invert(100%);  
    }
}
```

In `not webkit` browsers, do it manually using `@media print`.

Comment: This method worked perfectly for my purposes. However I used html{} instead of body{} for the entire page and all its contents to be inverted. I then used an additional img{} tag to invert all the images back to their original color.

Answer (score 3):

Why not specify those styles in the `@media print` media query? Google can help, but [here is one site with an explanation](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/08/tips-tricks-print-style-sheets/).

Comment: `@print media` or `@media print`?

Comment: Due to the large number of backgrounds and objects in the site, I was hoping to find an alternative to manually changing each style. Something like an inverted-color canvas if that's possible (with exception of a few images).

Comment: @italo: Haha, thanks for catching my typo. Fixed now.

Comment: @hhaus: Probably you should have been working with a simpler stylesheet from the beginning. It may be impractical for you to refactor at this point, but it's probably worth the effort. Things like backgrounds and font colors at the page level should be as minimally specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a print stylesheet and invert the colours in there...

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/